# How to reassemble the data.frame back to array when handling an image?

Tags: r, image

To better working with the image, it would be much easier to read the image and split it into channels like RGB. But when the manipulation is done, I just don't knowhow to reassemble the data.frame back to image array, Please advise.

```
library(jpeg)
library(magrittr)
IMG <- readJPEG("r-logo.jpg") %>% melt %>% dcast(Var1+Var2~Var3, value.var="value")  #read the image file in, and break it as data.frame.
names(IMG) <- c("W", "H", "R", "G", "B") # identify the columns

IMG$B <-0  # image manipulation, say, remove the BLUE channel.

 head(IMG)
#   W H R G B
# 1 1 1 1 1 0
# 2 1 2 1 1 0
# 3 1 3 1 1 0
# 4 1 4 1 1 0
# 5 1 5 1 1 0
# 6 1 6 1 1 0
```

How can I make the changed IMG data.frame back to array class, so I can save it back? Many thanks.

[image]

Per the suggestion by @Mike, I tried

```
IMG <- as.matrix(IMG) 
IMG3 <- array(IMG, dim =c(340,768,3))
```

But the result is quite different. Pls see the 2 snapshoot.
[image]
[image]

as mentioned, I would like to remove the RED channel, so, the result should be like this.
[image]

Comment: You can do something like this: `IMG <- as.matrix(IMG)

IMG3 <- array(IMG, dim =c(340,768,3))` .However, I do not know if this give the right image back.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike. But the results are quite different. Seems not working.

Comment: the `as.matrix` turned all numeric variables into integers unfortunately. You can over come that by making everything a numeric variable before `as.matrix`. What is the expected Image supposed to look like?

Comment: @Mike, I just updated the post. The result shall be like the last image by removing the red channel.